# Не работает фильтр Command в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Начал писать очередного бота, сделал один хэндлер

```py
from aiogram import types

async def restart(command: types.Message):
    await command.reply('Какое-нибудь приветствие ¯\_(ツ)_/¯')
```

Дальше зарегистрировал его:

```py
# тут все импорты

async def start():
    dp = Dispatcher()
    bot = Bot(API_TOKEN)

    dp.message.register(restart, Command(commands=['start', 'stop', 'cancel'])
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())
```

Ну тут всё понятно, но когда запустил и проверил команду, то в логах обнаружилось вот это:

```
Cause exception while process update id=649896428 by bot id=6419449955
TypeError: restart() got multiple values for argument 'command'
```

Вообще никогда не сталкивался с таким, на форумах тоже ничего нет, помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, с которой вы столкнулись, указывает на то, что функции restart() передается несколько значений для аргумента command.

Основная причина этой ошибки заключается в неправильном вызове register метода для регистрации хэндлера команды. Вы должны передать функцию restart без вызова или передачи аргументов.

В вашем случае, исправьте следующую строку:

```
dp.message.register(restart, Command(commands=['start', 'stop', 'cancel'])
```

на

```
dp.message.register(restart, commands=['start', 'stop', 'cancel'])
```

Таким образом, вы не будете передавать аргумент command в restart() функцию при регистрации хэндлера команды, и ошибка должна быть исправлена.

Comment: Но у меня третья версия aiogram, а таким образом хэндлеры регистрировались во второй версии. Я попробовал этот вариант, вот вывод:

```
This error may be caused when you are trying to register filters like in 2.x version of this framework, if it's true just look at correspoding documentation pages.
Please remove the {'commands'} arguments from this call
```

Answer (score 0):

Не используй command для обозначения самого Message. Переименуй в message или msg. command используется для передачи команды в хендлер, потому у тебя возникает конфликт

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.filters import CommandObject

async def restart(message: types.Message, command: CommandObject):
    await message.reply('Какое-нибудь приветствие ¯\_(ツ)_/¯')
```

```
CommandObject
Instance of this object is always has command and it prefix. Can be passed as keyword argument **command** to the handler
```

Comment: Спасибо)) Вообще не думал, что название аргумента может иметь какое-то значение, теперь всё работает